# Does Maximum a posterior(MAP) estimate of weights in Linear Regression avoid over fitting?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, posterior

I am new to machine learning. In an online course that I am taking the instructor claims the following: in linear regression, MLE framework gives us the squared loss cost function which overfits. In order to overcome that we use MAP estimate of the weights. I would like to get a theoretical reason behind why MLE overfits(if it indeed does so) and why using MAP we are able to overcome that(if we can indeed do so).

Comment: Why do you think that either of your statements - the one about MLE overfitting and MAP not overfitting in linear regression - is true?  Note that if you use uniform / diffuse priors, the two will coincide...

Comment: I do not if they are true or not. I saw it here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtkGq9tdYcI&t=0s&index=59&list=PLD0F06AA0D2E8FFBA

Comment: @AbhayGupta neither MLE does overfit in general, nor MAP solves any problem with overfitting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overfitting is usually related to the number of degrees of freedom of the model vs. the data.
It is not related to the method to estimate / calculate the parameters related to those degrees of freedom.

Hence either MAP or MLE doesn't create Overfitting in case the model is correctly chosen.